# "Events" on matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

With the below set of data I would like to have a graph with a `"RESTART"` `sign/flag` at the time of the reboot there. Is it possible?

```
00:50   2.3 
01:00   2.8 
01:10   3.4 
01:20   3.9 

RESTART

01:50   0.4 
02:00   0.5
```

I was searching for something like `"matplotlib events"` but that seemed to be misleading as it was pointing me to events like zoom-in/zoom-out on the graph.

EDIT:

I see that it may be a little complicated then I expected. So far I have this code:

```
load = np.array([2.3,
2.8,
3.4,
3.9,
0.4,
0.5,
])

x = [datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(6)]

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

plt.plot(x, load)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

As I cannot just put "RESTART" in the array (and it would not make much sense anyway), I am thinking about some other way on how to find out that some event happened during the captured data. Any ideas? Thanks !!!

Comment: can you post your attempt or some code you write for the plot?

Comment: If you can set a time for your event, you can use [`plt.vlines`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines) (probably with setting a `hold` keyword) to draw a vertical line over your plot.

Comment: Thanks mate, this is exactly what i needed! Can you please put it as answer so I can mark it?